# How to set JSESSIONID in cookie on php curl?

Tags: php, curl, jsessionid

Im trying to integrate 3rd part API in PHP curl.

It is working fine and got the response when I tried in `postman`. But it is not working in my PHP CURL code.

[image]
I find the there is JSESSIONID is set in header in postman. I don't know how to create that JSESSIONID in php curl and set in cookies.

Anyone know about this?

**PHP code**

```
$url = "http://website.com/Public/login/";
$dataa["userNo"] = "username";
$dataa["userPassword"] = "password";

$data = json_encode($dataa);

$ch = curl_init($url);

$headers = array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        "Cookie: JSESSIONID=2cba2d9d7dc5455b76t90f4ccac3; httpOnly"
    );


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// Instruct cURL to store cookies in this file.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');

// Instruct cURL to read this file when asked about cookies.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');

$response1 = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$res = json_decode($response1,true);
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code?

Comment: @NicoHaase, Thanks for your answer. But its not working. I have updated my code in question section

Comment: "Not working" is a pretty broad description of your problem. Can you explain what that means?

Comment: there is no value in cookies file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you're accessing is trying to set cookies.

To accept cookies with cURL, you'll need to specify a "cookie jar", a file where cURL can store the cookies it receives:

```php
// Instruct cURL to store cookies it receives in this file.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');

// Instruct cURL to read this file when asked about cookies.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
```

---

`JSESSIONID` sounds like a "session ID" cookie, something that keeps track of a session, or a series of requests. The session ID `2cba2d9d7dc5455b76t90f4ccac3` is tied to the session you started with Postman, you'll need to remove that from your PHP request.

Comment: More specifically, there's no point in inventing your own `JSESSIONID` value. It won't work.

Comment: just changed cookies file path like `./cookies.txt`

Comment: @Vel You possibly want a dedicated directory for cookie data and similar stuff (as in the answer) rather than using current working directory and storing temporary files scattered among your source code.